# How to project RGB multiband GeoTIFF to specified area extent using python?

Tags: python, image, matplotlib-basemap, rasterio

I want to plot and RGB image (because it is satellite image) from multiband GeoTIFF and project it to specified area extent.

Recently, I was successfully able to do this with single band raster using "georaster". However, when I tried to do the same for multiband raster, after calling `image = georaster.MultiBandRaster(file, bands='all', load_data=extent)` to load the subset data the same way as with georaster.SingleBandRaster, I get the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "slovakia.py", line 15, in
>   
>       image = georaster.MultiBandRaster(file, bands='all', load_data=extent)   File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/georaster/georaster.py", line
>   1249, in **init**
>       if self.r == None: ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

When I was unable to load subset of multiband data, I tried to create and RGB image from 3 bands, which are contained in GeoTIFF, without projecting it to basemap. However, the result is quite surprising.

```
import georaster
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
from matplotlib.pyplot import figure
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.cm as cm

file = "/home/lubomir/Desktop/Sentinel3_SLSTR/RGB/SLSTR_201901100859_Natural_Color.tif"
defllon = 16
defllat = 47
defulon = 23
defulat = 50.5
extent = (defllon,defulon,defllat,defulat)

image = georaster.MultiBandRaster(file, bands='all')
resulting_image = np.array(image.r[:,:,:], dtype='float32')
print resulting_image.shape

m = Basemap(epsg=3395,llcrnrlat=47,urcrnrlat=50.5,\
            llcrnrlon=16,urcrnrlon=23,resolution='i')
m.drawcoastlines(linewidth=1, color='g', zorder=2)
m.drawcountries(linewidth=1, color='m', zorder=2)
m.imshow(resulting_image, origin='upper', zorder=1, cmap=cm.gray)

plt.savefig('test.tiff',dpi=600,transparent=True,bbox_inches=None,frameon=False)
plt.show()
resulting_image=None
```

Single band raster projected to specified area:
[Single_band](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2NHjb.jpg)

RGB image composed from 3 bands:
[RGB_image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SEisG.jpg)

While band 2 of the GeoTIF looks like this: 
[band2_greyscale](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j6h6y.jpg)

I will welcome any help or suggestions regarding *subset data loading of MultiBandRaster* or *RGB ploting of MultiBandRaster.* I would be alsothankful for any other python methods on how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I've had a very similar issue when using georaster.MultiBandRaster. After switching to georaster.SingleBandRaster, the error message "ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous." went away, and I was able to display a single  band plot. To match with the basemap contour, it also required to execute a 180 degree flip operation with the statement: np.flipud(image.r). In summary, there seems to be an issue, likely related to Python >= 3.6 or numpy version, which causes the error message during the function georaster.MultiBandRaster. I will open a new post for it.